# Square API Won't Return List of Locations - Invalid Request Error

Tags: php, api, square, square-connect

Here is my code:

```
// Build request URL
$url = 'https://connect.squareup.com/v2/locations/';

// Build and execute CURL request
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, // return web page
    CURLOPT_HEADER => false, // don't return headers
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true, // follow redirects
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10, // stop after 10 redirects
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "", // handle compressed
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true, // set referrer on redirect
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120, // time-out on connect
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120, // time-out on response
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET', 
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accessToken,
        'Accept: application/json',
    ) 
);

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

$content = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
var_dump($content);
```

Here is what I get back:

```
string(158) "{"errors":[{"category":"INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR","code":"NOT_FOUND","detail":"API endpoint for URL path `/v2/locations/` and HTTP method `GET` is not found."}]}"
```

I am pounding my head on this one... I tried using the Square SDK but calling from it doesn't return a list of locations either.

I have created an application on the Square Developer Dashboard. $accessToken is set to the sandbox access token listed there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added an extra `/` at the end of the url. You should instead use:

`$url = 'https://connect.squareup.com/v2/locations';`

Other than that your code works!